# How to pass parameter from JS to Controller in ASP API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, parameters

I'm running LINQ queries against a DB model of traffic data.
The html page has a dropdown menu from which I will get a selectedInjury value to modify the query results (it is mocked here).  I cannot figure out how to pass the value to the Controller.

Each variation I've tried responds with

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is the Javascript I'm trying to get working:

```
var mockSelectedInjury = "FATAL";
$.getJSON("/api/query1/selectedInjury", mockSelectedInjury)
    .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, crash) {
            $('<li>', { text: formatCrashReport(crash) }).appendTo($('#crashTable'));
        });
    });
```

This is the method I've written in the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using final.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace final.Controllers
{
public class CrashController : ApiController
{
    ChicagoTrafficEntities myEntities = new ChicagoTrafficEntities();

    [Route("api/query1")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetQuery(string selectedInjury)
    {
        List<CrashReport> returnList = new List<CrashReport>();

        //get a selection of all the data where injury matches
        var records = from report in myEntities.CrashReports
                      where report.MostSevereInjury == selectedInjury
                      select new
                      {
                          PrimeContributingCause = report.PrimeContributingCause,
                      };

        // add the query items to a list
        foreach (var item in records)
        {
            CrashReport temp = new CrashReport
            {
                PrimeContributingCause = item.PrimeContributingCause
            };
            returnList.Add(temp);
        }

        // create a new query from that set that includes a count of the 
        // occurrences of the injury per the primeCause.
        var foo = returnList.GroupBy(n => n.PrimeContributingCause).
                Select(group =>
                    new
                    {
                        PrimeContributingCause = group.Key,
                        NumberInjuries = group.Count()
                    }).OrderByDescending(n => n.NumberInjuries);

        return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Json(foo)));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this a copy&paste error or an actual typo? `$.getJSON("/api/query1/selecteInjury", mockSelectedInjury)` is missing a **d** in `selectedInjury`.

Comment: yes that is a typo in the code.  Excuse me.  It is fixed, but it also does not change my results.

Answer (score 0):

If your Web API expects a URL that looks like `api/query1/FATAL`, then you should construct the URL in JavaScript accordingly:

```
var mockSelectedInjury = "FATAL";
$.getJSON("/api/query1/" + mockSelectedInjury)
   .done(function (data) {
      // ...
    });
```

**Alternative: Using query parameters**

If you want to send Query-Parameters (instead of parameters being part of the path), then you construct an object and pass that as the second parameter:

```
var paramContainer = {'selectedInjury': 'FATAL'};
$.getJSON("/api/query1", paramContainer)
   .done(function (data) {
        // ...
    });
```

The signature of your API method would look like this:

```
[Route("api/query1")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetQuery(string selectedInjury)
{
}
```

Comment: Neither solution worked.  Same response.  I know the controller works with a plain GetAllFoo() request, using the built-in, but it's broken once I try implementing this customized response.  I've modified the initial post to include the entire controller class as it stands now.

Comment: @Bretonator Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the server to see whether the request even reaches the correct method?

Comment: I will try and see.